# Animation view after dismiss

Tags: animation, uiview, ios8, ios9

I'm having a problem about animation.

In View Controller, I have a contentView with frame `(0,0,320,200)`. From View Controller, I pressed a button to open the camera and take pictures from there. Then I dismissed the camera view.

At the moment, I set animation for contentView with new frame `(0,200,320,200)`, but it doesn't work in this case. This is my animation code after dismissing:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     _contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,200,320,200);
                }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }
 ];
```

Comment: Can you show more code. From where u r calling this method

Comment: I solved this problem. I put code in viewdidappear and it worked. Thanks